# Unable to initialize CameraController Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, bloc

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-taking-pictures-with-the-bloc-pattern-76e38690df28) tutorial to build camera access using bloc pattern.

The problem is that when I try to open the page that should show me what the camera sees to take a picture I receive the error `"Null check operator used on a null value"`. Null value in this case is `CameraController`.

CameraUtils, class needed :

```
class CameraUtils {
  Future<CameraController> getCameraController(
      ResolutionPreset resolutionPreset) async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    final camera = cameras.first;

    return CameraController(
      camera,
      resolutionPreset,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888,
    );
  }

  Future<String> getPath() async => join(
        (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
        '${DateTime.now()}.png',
      );
}
```

This is my `BlocCamera` class :

```
class CameraBloc extends Bloc<CameraEvent, CameraState> {
  late final CameraUtils _cameraUtils;
  late final ResolutionPreset _resolutionPreset;
  late final CameraLensDirection _cameraLensDirection;

  CameraController? _controller;

  late File pictureTaken;

  CameraBloc() : super(CameraInitial()) {
    _cameraUtils = CameraUtils();
    _resolutionPreset = ResolutionPreset.high;
    _cameraLensDirection = CameraLensDirection.back;
    on<CameraInitialized>(_onCameraInitialized);
    on<CameraCaptured>(_onCameraCaptured);
    on<CameraStopped>(_onCameraStopped);
    add(CameraInitialized());
  }

  Stream<CameraState> _onCameraInitialized(
      CameraInitialized event, emit) async* {
    try {
      _controller = await _cameraUtils.getCameraController(_resolutionPreset);
      await _controller!.initialize();
      yield CameraReady();
    } on CameraException catch (error) {
      _controller!.dispose();
      yield CameraFailure(error: error.description ?? "Camera generic error");
    } catch (error) {
      yield CameraFailure(error: error.toString());
    }
  }

  Stream<CameraState> _onCameraCaptured(CameraCaptured event, emit) async* {
    if (state is CameraReady) {
      yield CameraCaptureInProgress();
      try {
        final path = await _cameraUtils.getPath();
        await _controller?.takePicture();
        yield CameraCaptureSuccess(path: path);
      } on CameraException catch (error) {
        yield CameraCaptureFailure(
            error: error.description ?? "Generic camera capture failure");
      }
    }
  }

  Stream<CameraState> _onCameraStopped(CameraStopped event, emit) async* {
    _controller?.dispose();
    yield CameraInitial();
  }

  void initController() async {
    _controller = await _cameraUtils.getCameraController(_resolutionPreset);
    await _controller!.initialize();
  }

  CameraController getController() => _controller!;

  void getCamera() => add(CameraInitialized());
}
```

In this case I tried to initialise `CameraController` at the beginning with `add(CameraInitialized())` inside Bloc constructor

Then I try to show camera with :

```
class CameraView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CameraView> createState() => _CameraViewState();
}
class _CameraViewState extends State<CameraView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CameraPreview(BlocProvider.of<CameraBloc>(context).getController());
}
}
```

If you want to reproduce the example just copy paste `BlocCamera` class and navigate to `CameraView` page.

I think I'm not able to well initialise the `CameraController` before asking for it.